# Embedded Roboflow MODEL Into a React webapp to facilitate analysing accuracy of an image to its ideal model

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, computer-vision, roboflow

I am currently developing a webapp through ionic react. It is done however I wish to add a function where user can upload image(s) to check the percentage of it matching a model image. (e.g how alike it looks to an apple). So post uploading the image, it would be great if the app can refer the image to the roboflow model, calculate its accuracy/give image output to view its similarity.

I have tried to look up resources relating to this however found quite little. My team and I are first time users of embedding this solution into react as well, and hence would love to know the best wats we can carry this out. Many Thanks!!! Your inputs are highly appreciated!